# JSON parser doesn't work

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

For some reason my json twitter parser isn't working?

Anyone got any ideas as to why?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function outputHtmlToDiv(tweet,i){
      count = i + 1;
      $('#wrapper #sidebar .profile').html('<img src="'+tweet.profile_image_url+'" alt="Pretty Klicks" />');
    }
        $(document).ready(function(){

        var url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/prettyklicks.json?count=1';

            $.getJSON(url,function(json){
                $.each(json.user,function(i,tweet){
                  outputHtmlToDiv(tweet,i);
                });
              });

        });


</script>
```

Comment: What is not working as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors, mainly you need `&callback=?` in the url, like this:

```
 var url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/prettyklicks.json?count=1&callback=?';
```

Otherwise jQuery doesn't know to make a JSONP request (a normal XHR request is blocked cross-domain, complements of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)).  Also your get structure's a bit off, the *base* object is an array, overall it should look like this:

```
function outputHtmlToDiv(tweet, i) {
  count = i + 1;
  $('#wrapper #sidebar .profile').html('<img src="'+tweet.user.profile_image_url+'" alt="Pretty Klicks" />');
}
$(function(){
  var url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/prettyklicks.json?count=1&callback=?';
  $.getJSON(url,function(json){
    $.each(json,function(i,tweet){
      outputHtmlToDiv(tweet,i);
    });
  });
});​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/kJBCe/2/), since `json` in the object above is an array of tweets, you need to loop through that array directly, `json.user` will be undefined (Array doesn't have a property called `users`), `json[0].user` however, is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Missing quote after `'+tweet.profile_image_url+'`

Try this:

```
$('#wrapper #sidebar .profile').html('<img src="'+tweet.profile_image_url+'" alt="Pretty Klicks" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that because you have unclosed quote after img/src?

Intead of:

```
$('#wrapper #sidebar .profile').html('<img src="'+tweet.profile_image_url+' alt="Pretty Klicks" />');
```

Try:

```
$('#wrapper #sidebar .profile').html('<img src="'+tweet.profile_image_url+'" alt="Pretty Klicks" />');
```

Comment: as I commented above, unfortunately that was just a type, still doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a JSONP callback parameter (see [the documentation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Things-Every-Developer-Should-Know#5Parametershavecertainexpectations)).  With jQuery, you can just use a ? and it will generate a name:

```
var url = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/prettyklicks.json?count=1&callback=?';
```